# How to change function implementation for automatically generated partial class?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, partial-classes

`Visual Studio` automatically generated a partial `class` in my project, containing a `function` whose implementation I want to change.

Is this doable without losing the changes I made whenever the `class` is automatically generated again?

Example:

```
Partial Public Class INO_Opportunity
    Private Function IsLocalFileSystemWebService(ByVal url As String) As Boolean
        ' Here I want to add code

        ' All the following code is generated by VS:
        If ((url Is Nothing) OrElse (url Is String.Empty)) Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim wsUri As System.Uri = New System.Uri(url)

        If ((wsUri.Port >= 1024) AndAlso (String.Compare(wsUri.Host, "localHost", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0)) Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Is this in a .designer.vb file?

Comment: Maybe. Or No. You can subclass it to create a different implementation, or create an overload in your code. Or there may be a way to get the generator to not generate and instead accept an implementation you provide. Or there may be a way to hook into it with events.  To get a good answer to this you're going to have to post the generated code and say how you want to change it, so we can understand what is generating, how and how to plug into it

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's in a `Reference.vb` file generated from a `WSDL`.

Comment: @CaiusJard I added a code snippet.

Comment: Do you want to add code because some other thing is calling `IsLocalFileSystemWebService` and you want to alter the reply, or are you calling `IsLocalFileSystemWebService` ?

Comment: I want to alter the reply.